# Tengo que añadir texto a un fichero.odt con java

Tags: java

tengo un fichero libreoffice y tengo que agregarle mas texto debajo del que ya tiene, lo leo pero no me deja escribir.

muchas gracias.

Este es mi código.

```
btnTrabajadoresESCRIBIR.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            GesEscOdt aux = new GesEscOdt();
            String aux2 = aux.gesEscOdt();
            
            try {
                FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(".//ficheros//trabajadores.odt");
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
                
                PrintWriter escribir = new PrintWriter(out);
                escribir.println(aux2);
                escribir.flush();
                escribir.close();
               
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error: "+ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow!!!, te recomiendo revisar la sección [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), luego edita tu pregunta y no olvides agregar el código que tienes hecho, lo que has tratado o investigado. Saludos ;)

Comment: ¿Debe ser obligatoriamiente en Java? Libreoffice viene con un interprete "libreoffice basic" integrado para macros que quizás te sea más fácil.

Comment: si tiene que ser desde java.

Answer (score 0):

Con el mero FileWriter posiblemente no alcance, pues hay que adaptar lo que vas a añadir, al estándar odf. Tal como sucede con otros archivos de ofimática (puedes intentar abrir los docx y xlsx con un visor de archivos zip...), acá hay que usar una librería especializada.

No es trivial encontrarla porque la han movido bastante, pero está [ODFDOM](https://odftoolkit.org/odfdom/index.html), mantenida por la misma gente de LibreOffice.

Un ejemplo de uso básico que dan es:

```
// Create a text document from a standard template (empty documents within the JAR)
OdfTextDocument odt = OdfTextDocument.newTextDocument();
// Append text to the end of the document.
odt.addText("This is my very first ODF test");
// Save document
odt.save("MyFilename.odt");
```

Hay otro tutorial recomendado por la misma gente de LibreOffice para usar esta librería [aquí](http://www.langintro.com/odfdom_tutorials/create_odt.html).